# FlashList child component render behaviour

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, flash-list

I have a `FlashList` that takes a custom popup as a child component as seen in the picture below, the problem now is on first click, the popup is above the content of the `FlashList` card item as seen in picture one.

[image]

The problem now is that on subsequent clicks the modal is below the content of `FlashList` card item.

[image]

Below is the code for the card

```
const PlanDrugCard: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  drug,
  noOfTablets,
  backgroundColor,
  textColor,
  id,
  onModalOpen,
  onEditPress,
  onSharePress,
  onDeletePress,
  onModalClose,
  modalVisible,
  startDate,
  endDate,
  dosage,
  item,
  status,
  statusBackgroundColor,
  statusTextColor,
  // setModalVisible,
}) => {
  const Popup = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.modalView}>
        <View style={styles.cancelContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onModalClose}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="close" size={20} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        {onEditPress && (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.textPress} onPress={onEditPress}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Edit</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}

        <View style={styles.divider} />

        {onSharePress && (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.textPress} onPress={onSharePress}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Share</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}

        <View style={styles.divider} />

        {onDeletePress && (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.textPress} onPress={onDeletePress}>
            <Text style={[styles.titleText, { color: "#DD2E44" }]}>Delete</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  const MemoizedPopup = memo(Popup);

  return (
    <VStack style={styles.container}>
      {modalVisible[id] && <MemoizedPopup />}
      <HStack
        justifyContent={"space-between"}
        alignItems={"center"}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 16,
            color: COLORS.primary,
            textAlign: "left",
            fontWeight: "500",
          }}
        >
          {drug}
        </Text>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onModalOpen}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="dots-vertical" size={24} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </HStack>

      <HStack
        style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
        justifyContent={"space-between"}
        paddingRight={2.5}
      >
        <View
          style={[styles.coloredText, { backgroundColor: backgroundColor }]}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: textColor, fontSize: 13, fontWeight: "600" }}>
            {dosage} {dosage === "1" ? "tablet" : "tablets"}{" "}
            {noOfTablets === 1 ? "" : noOfTablets}{" "}
            {noOfTablets === 1 ? "Once" : "Times"} Daily
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View
          style={[
            styles.coloredText,
            { backgroundColor: statusBackgroundColor },
          ]}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              color: statusTextColor,
              fontSize: 13,
              fontWeight: "600",
              textTransform: "capitalize",
            }}
          >
            {status}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </HStack>

      {/* <HStack style={{ marginTop: 10, marginRight: 12 }} justifyContent={'space-between'}>
                <Text style={{ color: COLORS.gray3, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: "500" }}>Start: {startDate}</Text>
                <Text style={{ color: COLORS.gray3, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: "500" }}>End: {endDate}</Text>
            </HStack> */}
    </VStack>
  );
};
```

This is the `FlashList` implementation;

```
interface ModalVisibilityState {
  [id: string]: boolean;
}

const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState<ModalVisibilityState>({});

const handleModalOpen = (id: string) => {
  setModalVisible((prev) => {
    const updatedModals = { ...prev };

    // Check if the current modal is already open
    if (updatedModals[id]) {
      // If it's open, close it
      updatedModals[id] = false;
    } else {
      // If it's not open, close any other open modals
      Object.keys(updatedModals).forEach((modalId) => {
        if (modalId !== id) {
          updatedModals[modalId] = false;
        }
      });

      // Open the modal with the specified id
      updatedModals[id] = true;
    }

    console.log("Modal opened for:", id);
    return updatedModals;
  });
};

const handleModalClose = (id: string) => {
  setModalVisible((prev) => ({ ...prev, [id]: false }));
  // console.log('Closing Modal for:', id);
};

<FlashList
  data={filteredData}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 20 }}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
  }
  ListHeaderComponent={() => (
    <Text
      style={{
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: "600",
        color: "#2a2a2a",
        textAlign: "left",
        marginBottom: 20,
      }}
    >
      All Medications
    </Text>
  )}
  renderItem={({ item, index }: { item: DrugData; index: number }) => (
    <PlanDrugCard
      // key={item._id}
      drug={item.name}
      noOfTablets={item.timesDaily}
      startDate={item.fromWhen.toString().split("T")[0]}
      endDate={item.tillWhen.toString().split("T")[0]}
      dosage={item.dosage.split("-")[0]}
      backgroundColor={
        item.timesDaily === 1
          ? "#1C49B429"
          : item.timesDaily === 2
          ? "#F7876429"
          : "#2F8C1829"
      }
      textColor={
        item.timesDaily === 1
          ? "#1C49B4"
          : item.timesDaily === 2
          ? "#F78764CC"
          : "#2F8C18"
      }
      onModalOpen={() => handleModalOpen(item._id)}
      onEditPress={() => handleEdit(item._id)}
      onSharePress={() => handleShare(item._id)}
      onDeletePress={() => handleDelete(item._id)}
      onModalClose={() => handleModalClose(item._id)}
      modalVisible={modalVisible}
      id={item._id}
      item={item}
      status={item.status}
      statusTextColor={item.status === "active" ? "#2F8C18" : "#DC143C"}
      statusBackgroundColor={
        item.status === "active" ? "#2F8C1829" : "#DC143C29"
      }
      // setModalVisible={setModalVisible}
    />
  )}
  estimatedItemSize={20}
  extraData={modalVisible}
  onLoad={onLoadListener}
  // disableAutoLayout={true}
/>;
```

I have tried increasing the `zIndex` of the popup to the highest but same result. I'd appreciate if anyone can help with this issue.